# How do I solve an indefinite integral where dx is involved?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I do not know how to evaluate the integral below, where $dx$ is in the numerator of the integrand:

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{9+x^2}$$

I would appreciate if somebody could walk me through the evaluation.

Comment: For now you can think  of $dx$ as showing you what you are integrating with respect to.

Comment: So do I just leave dx as it us on top?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I've never seen an integral without $dx$ (assuming we are integrating w.r.t. $x$). Are you sure you have sufficient background in integration?

Comment: the numerator is $1 \times dx$

Comment: Hem, $dx$ is always *in the numerator of the integrand*. Do you understand this notation ?

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, as I mentioned in the comments you can think of $dx$ as showing you that you are integrating with respect to $x$. Now for your integral we must perform a substitution.

We will use the substitution $x = 3\tan u$ which also yields that $dx/du = 3 \sec^2 u$

That means we can rewrite our integral like this

$$\int \frac{1}{9 + x^2} \frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{du}dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{9 + (3\tan u)^2} 3\sec^2u\frac{du}{dx}dx$$
$$\int \frac{3\sec^2 u}{9(1 + \tan^2 u)} du$$
Now look how we are integrating with respect to $u$. Using the trig identity $1 + \tan^2u = \sec^2u$
$$\int \frac{1}{3}du  = \frac{u}{3} + C$$

Now substituting $x$ back in 
$$\int \frac{1}{9 + x^2} dx = \frac{\arctan(\frac{x}{3})}{3} + C$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}(\mathrm{arctan}(ax)) = \frac{a}{1+(ax)^2}
\end{equation}

$a\in\mathbb{R}$ is a fixed number.

Try to adapt your integral to use the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is due to the $dx$ being within the fraction. Your integral is equivalent to:
$$\int \frac{dx}{9+x^2}=\int \frac{1}{9+x^2}~dx$$

---

To solve it, substitute:
$$x=3\tan{\theta} \implies dx=3\sec^2{\theta}~d{\theta}$$
This gives:
$$\int \frac{1}{9+x^2}~dx=\int \frac{1}{9+9\tan^2{\theta}}\cdot 3\sec^2{\theta}~d{\theta}$$
Now, use the identity:
$$1+\tan^2{\theta}\equiv \sec^2{\theta}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Yes that is where my confusion lies, thank you. Why do you substitute those for x and dx? Do you do the same for every question that is similar to this? Thanks.

Comment: It is just a convenient choice of variables in this case since we can cancel a lot of variables. No, you can't do the same substitution for every question.

Comment: See [Trigonometric Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution).